# User authentication best practices

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have an app on GAE that checks if an administrator is logged in before it calls any webpage.  I have tried various methods to manage the login process.

**Q1** - What am I doing wrong with my decorator in example two?
**Q2** - Does one normally do this check on the **post** function too?

Before I used an if statement in each get function.  The problem is that I would repeat this if statement over and over in each function.

```
class IncomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    if users.is_current_user_admin():
      self.response.write('My Webpage')
    else:
      self.response.write('Please Login')
```

Then I tried to make a decorator do that for me.  It didn't work so what am I doing wrong.

```
def check(func):
  if users.is_current_user_admin():
    return func
  else:
    response.write('Please Login') ### Doesn't work

class IncomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @check
  def get(self):
      self.response.write('My Webpage')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a decorator. A decorator needs to return a wrapper function that is called in place of the actual function, and it's the wrapper that needs to do the test and then call the original.

```
def check(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if users.is_current_user_admin():
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      response.write('Please Login')
  return wrapper
```

Comment: You won't have access to response at that point in the decorator.  The first argument in `args` will be `self`  so you would need to pull that out and call response from that. it would probably look like `args[0].response.write()`

Comment: My last question, do I need to use this on my post functions?

Comment: Well that depends on whether you're worried that non-admin people can post data to your app. You probably are, so in that case you should.

Answer (score 4):

If all users of the handler must be logged in and be `admin`, then you can specify the restriction in the app.yaml rather than in your code.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status

And would look something like

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: somefile.application
  login: admin
```

Be sure to read the docs completely not just skim. It is clear that you have some additional options

> auth_fail_action
>
> Describes the action taken when login is present and the user is not
>   logged in. Has two possible values:
>
> redirect (the default). The user is redirected to the Google sign-in
>   page, or /_ah/login_required if OpenID authentication is used. The
>   user is redirected back to the application URL after signing in or
>   creating an account. unauthorized. The request is rejected with an
>   HTTP status code of 401 and an error message.

Further down in the document you will see examples.

Comment: I tried this but could not figure out how to redirect the user to a login page that says 'Please Login' for example.

Comment: Thanks but how would I redirect the user to my own custom error page.  I have tried to use the Webapp2 Error handlers but cant get them to work for error 401 nor get it to redirect to my own url.

Comment: If your using google auth service you can't send them to a customer login page.  Thats by design. If your using your own auth scheme then app.yaml based securing won't be appropriate. In that case you your own decorator, or look further into webapp2 decorator.  I don't use webapp2 at all, so my knowledge in this area is limited.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your own decorator or securing via app.yaml.

webapp2 (which you are using ) has decorators for the handler to do what you require

See https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/users.html